# Find multiple urls with regex

Tags: swift, regex

I need to find multiple urls within a string. The regex I'm using is

`(https?:\/\/.*\.(?:png|jpg))`

and the string is
`Newhttps://www.findregexhere.com/newimage.pngfrhttps://www.findregexhere.com/newimage.pngnewimage`

Here is the code I am using

```
let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: "https?:\/\/.*\.(?:png|jpg)$", options: .caseInsensitive)
let nsString = text as NSString
let results = regex.matches(in: text, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: nsString.length))
```

but the result is giving me this

`https://www.findregexhere.com/newimage.pngfrhttps://www.findregexhere.com/newimage.png`

Comment: Maybe use non-greedy with `(https?:\/\/.*?\.(?:png|jpg))`

Comment: Example: https://regex101.com/r/AK5foS/1

Comment: Thanks @MDR It worked. Do you mind posting this as answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Np.  Done.  Glad it helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try non-greedy with...

```
(https?:\/\/.*?\.(?:png|jpg))
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/AK5foS/1